# FireStore UI showing old data while Backend is up to date

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, webhooks

All of a sudden after deleting a collection Firestore started bugging.
Firebase web console is showing old data while the code running on my test server is showing new data, received from a tradingview(webhook).

LOGIC
each time there is a new trade signal. data is stored in Firestore and a client retrieves the data with a data listener. So I know if the data is new or old.

UnSYC screenshots
== FIRST PROOFS ==
proof signal is sent
[image: proof signal is sent]

proof signal is stored in firestore db
[image: proof signal is stored in firestore db]

proof firestore db UI is not synced
[image: proof firestore db UI is not synced]

== SECOND PROOFS ==
proof signal is sent again
[image: proof signal is sent again]

proof signal is stored in firestore db again
[image: proof signal is stored in firestore db again]

proof firestore db UI is not synced again
[image: proof firestore db UI is not synced again]

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: i dont have a debugging problem, my code works fine . the problem seems to be the user interface on my firestore console. It's froze in the past. my app queries show new data, and even no data (when a document is deleted). but I CANT TRACK CHANGES in user Interface. Its Like the UI is not synced with the actual data in the firestore database. This started out of the blue and NOT with some change in my code

Comment: Can you provide a sample screenshot that provides the UI not synced with the actual data in the firestore database.

Comment: its late here i'll start my app and take sample screenshot tomorrow but anyways i received an email regarding that database today maybe it is not just a coincidence. the email is about this: Client access to your Cloud Firestore database expired 20 day(s) ago.
They prompting me to edit the security rules

Comment: This can't be reproducible due to limited resources, I would suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) to further help you with your issue.

Comment: ok will do thnx